# How to prioritize openvpn traffic?

Tags: linux, openvpn, udp, traffic-shaping

I have an openvpn server, with one network interface. VPN traffic is extremely slow.
I tried to do traffic control with this configuration (currently):

```
qdisc del dev eth0 root
qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 12
class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 900mbit

#vpn
class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 1500kbit ceil 3000kbit prio 1
#local net
class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:11 htb rate 10mbit ceil 900mbit prio 2
#other
class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:12 htb rate 500kbit ceil 1000kbit prio 2

filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip sport 1194 0xffff flowid 1:10
filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 2 u32 match ip dst 192.168.10.0/24 flowid 1:11

qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:10 handle 10: sfq perturb 10
qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:11 handle 11: sfq perturb 10
qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:12 handle 12: sfq perturb 10
```

But it's still extremely slow.
I have an imaps connection that keeps transferring data continuously (I successfully limited the rate) but with openvpn I can't seem to get more than about 100kbit/s

The internet connection speed is about 3mbit/s (symmetric)

What could be the problem? Does the sport filter work for udp?

Comment: Note: the situation is about the same with a simple pfifo_fast or sfq (just the imaps connection uses almost all the available bandwidth), could it be an openvpn problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I switched openvpn over to tcp, and it seems to work much better now. Weird, but that's what I observed.
Maybe one of the internet connections doesn't handle udp well?

Comment: I had exactly opposite situation. I used to establish openvpn connections through TCP and latency was extremely high. When I switched it to UDP it became fine.